# If $ n= a_0 + a_1p+ \cdots +a_rp^r $, then show that $\frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1} \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)} + 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Write , for prime number $p$ and natural number $n \in \mathbb{N} $
$$ n= a_0 + a_1p+ \cdots +a_rp^r , \hspace{5mm} 0 \leq a_i \leq p-1$$

Then show that $$ \frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1} \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)} + 1$$

---

[My attempt]

I find $$ \frac{1}{p-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p^{-k}$$

Then, we show that $$ \frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1} = \sum \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_ip^{-k} \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)} + 1$$
but I don't know how to prove this.

Or $$ \frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1} \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)} + 1 \Longleftrightarrow \log(p) \frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1} \leq \log(n) + \log(p) \Longleftrightarrow p^{\frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1}} \leq np$$

Therefore, we show that $$ p^{\frac{\sum a_i}{ p-1} - 1} \leq n = a_0 + a_1p+ \cdots +a_rp^r $$

but I'm stuck here.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It seems that in your second approach the power of p is at most r using the same upper bound p-1 for each a_i. The assumption a_r is at least 1 might be natural if one expands n into p-adic system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is an easier way to prove your claim: observe that $\frac{\log(n)}{\log(p)}=\log_p(n)$. If we assume that $r$ is maximal such that $a_r\neq 0$, then $\log_p(n)\geq r$. Hence, the claim would follow if we proved that $\frac{\sum a_i}{p-1}\leq r-1$, or equivalently that $\sum_{i\leq r} a_i\leq (r+1)(p-1)$. But this follows from the fact that $a_i\leq p-1$ for every $i$.